# If a baby is born mid-flight, what happens visa-wise for them when they land in a foreign country, sans-passport?

Tags: visas, air-travel, passports, children

I [asked a similar question about what nationality a newborn midflight gets](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/35513/101), but I'm also now wondering - when they land, what happens? Normally you need a passport and possibly a visa to travel - so how are they usually processed when the plane lands with an extra person?

Comment: I wouldn't be too surprised by the immigration officials not having a procedure for this (and not wanting to deport the baby), and just pretending (at least officially) that the baby was born after the parents had cleared immigration, in which case, they don't have to do anything.

Comment: Immigration officials at most any larger airport will actually have a well-defined procedure for this, since an in-flight birth is just a type of medical emergency.  These happen quite frequently: some 44,000 times a year, according to the following estimate, although only a small portion of these land in a third country. http://www.ibtimes.com/how-common-are-medical-emergencies-commercial-airline-flights-1285859

Comment: @jpatokal I'm sure they have a procedure for a medical emergency which likely involves sending someone to the hospital with the patient, but that doesn't solve the problem of the baby not having papers.

Comment: All babies are born without papers, it's the parents' responsibility to sort them out.  As Greg's excellent answer outlines, emergency travel documents are meant precisely for this sort of thing.

Comment: @waiwai933: I think more to the point, they'll have a procedure for medical emergencies that cause someone (in this case an infant) to land in a country for which they have no visa (in this case the flight's scheduled destination). A medical emergency could cause a planeload of people, at least one of whom needs immediate hospitalization, to land in whatever country happens to be closest. I think that's sufficient grounds to expect immigration will have a plan for that *kind* of circumstance even if not specifically a birth.

Comment: ... and pretending the baby was born post-immigration might have huge consequences. For example, if US immigration officials were to pretend that then they'd be giving the baby US citizenship which it might not otherwise be entitled to. So I imagine they wouldn't do so without a policy saying they can, governments don't like it much when their officials throw a spanner in the works by lying to them ;-)

Comment: Since airlines often restrict flying at the end of a pregnancy, it cannot be too common. It could be more common (or least used to be more common) for ship travel.

Comment: Not quite the same situation, but many people do reach European countries without passport (often destroying it shortly before being found by the authorities). One common procedure in that case is to detain them, try to somehow guess/find out where they come from and get their consulate to recognize them as citizens and to provide some document that makes a deportation possible. People get rid of their passports specifically to try to prevent deportation.

Comment: @SteveJessop Yes but all those would typically be people with a passport. As an example, there is in fact a procedure in the relevant regulations to issue visas to people making an unplanned stop in the Schengen area but nothing is explicitly provided for people without travel documents. There might be some unpublished internal procedure about what to do in this case (which would presumably involve getting some emergency document from their consulate) but waiwai933's point still makes sense to me.

Comment: The short answer is it simply depends on the country(s) involved.  waiwai - in most countries, they would of course have totally establshed procedures for this. it's inconceivable they'd just "turn an eye".

Comment: What do the authorities do when a plane is evacuated on the runway? Presumably if the plane is in one piece then those not injured and without passports in hand could be penned up in immigration until the plane is cleared out and their passports recovered. If the plane's on fire, not so much. Anyway, my point is just that someone showing up without the proper documents, genuinely through no fault of their own, isn't a new scenario for immigration, they aren't likely to just stand there wondering what to do.

Comment: @SteveJessop They phone their boss to cover their asses?

Comment: gayot-fow's answer made me realize there's little in this question specific to airlines, the question would also apply to _ships_ between countries, and those used to take months, I would expect most countries have leftover laws from that time that would apply to airlines.

Comment: It occurs to me a counterpoint to this question is, who issues the death certificate when sadly older people pass away on a flight, perhaps over international waters, and in other situations??

Comment: @Relaxed: How can an airline "restrict flying at the end of a pregnancy"? Do they have gynecological exams in the security checkpoint to determine how many months? I can't see how this would even come up, especially since there are people big enough to look pregnant when they're not, and conversely some about to give birth who look like they're 7 months or less.

Comment: @R. Like any other rule: They write it in their conditions of carriage… Enforcement is another matter obviously.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I have direct experience with this; not actually in flight thank goodness, but in transit. My daughter was born prematurely in Shanghai last year during a short layover between Paris and Auckland. My wife and I only had limited 48-hour transit visas for China and our flight was due to depart about 10 hours after she was admitted to hospital at the beginning of labour.

It's a long story, so I'll focus on the visa parts and summarise.

- I (since my wife was in hospital at this point) got proper Chinese visas in our passports so that we could remain in China legally (this took several visits to the Chinese Exit-Entry Bureau (EEB)).
- After my daughter was born, we obtained an Emergency Travel Document (ETD) from the New Zealand Consulate in Shanghai.
- We got a Chinese visa for my daughter to put in her ETD, so that she would be permitted to leave China when she was ready (again, more EEB visits).
- The ETD allowed us to enter New Zealand (nearly two months later) and admit her to the NICU in Auckland (as, I discovered later, a permanent resident and not a citizen, but that qualified her for fully funded care).
- We applied for NZ citizenship for her recently so she would now have the same status as if she were born here in NZ.

Since she was born prematurely, she could not fly straight away and had to remain in a heated incubator with continuous medical care. If a full-term baby were born mid-flight or in transit, theoretically they could travel straight away but you would still probably have to modify travel plans just to sort out the paperwork.

Comment: "as, I discovered later, a permanent resident and not a citizen" If either you or your wife was a New Zealand citizen otherwise than by descent, your child would be automatically a New Zealand citizen at birth.

Comment: @user102008: Yes, that's true, but since she had not been officially documented as such she was not admitted as a citizen at that time.

Comment: I'm amazed (at first) that she wasn't considered a citizen - but I suppose getting these things takes time, and you wanted in to the country :)

Comment: @MarkMayo no doubt the fees involved in stamping the paperwork are a big reason for it...

Comment: "If a full-term baby were born mid-flight or in transit" ... then people in suits will ask why you chose to fly on or after your due date, and your answers might affect how sympathetically they treat you ;-)

Comment: @user102008 and Greg It's the next point that seems phrased in a slightly incorrect way. Presumably, you haven't applied for citizenship but you applied to have her citizenship recognized. (+1)

Comment: (Amazing that you have actual experience of the situation, Greg!!)  Here's a sort of vaguely related, err, tip if anyone else is possibly to have a baby on arrival in Shanghai!  Be sure to have some CHINESE CURRENCY, ON YOU, BEFORE You board in Europe or whatever. IME you need chinese currency to pay the small costs of visas etc, and, at Shanghai enyway there's no ATMs or change on the wrong side, very frustrating. So, err, this small tip may help anyone also experiencing a surprise birth!  :O

Comment: Though your answer is interesting, it is relevant only in the statistically very unlikely event that at least one of the parents is a NZ citizen, right?

Comment: @JoeBlow: We had exactly 130 € in our pocket when we landed; it wasn't a problem because there was a money exchange kiosk in the baggage claim area, and the short term transit visa (which was fairly new) was free. That part was planned and confirmed, of course. :)

Comment: @Relaxed: If you're curious about the details, see http://citizenship.govt.nz for the difference between *applying for citizenship by grant* and *claiming citizenship by descent*.

Comment: "there was a money exchange kiosk in the baggage claim area" -- WHAT ?!!  damn dude -- you mean in shanghai? what yr was this roughly??  amazing!  perhaps it's changed... did you have to deal with visas at that little "visa desk" sort of to the "left" if you're just about to exit to the open area?  thanks for the info! :)  again amazing story you have there ...

Comment: This was at Pudong airport in July 2013. I understand it got some significant upgrades in 2008 for the Olympics. First time to China for me, so I don't know what it was like before. :)

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek: The same procedure could be followed by citizens from most countries, I would say. In our case specifically, NZ was in fact not the only other country involved since both my wife and I hold dual nationalities. Like I said, it's a long story and my summary above covers just the key points.

Comment: @GregHewgill But did you apply for citizenship by grant or are you trying to claim it for your daughter?

Comment: @Relaxed: I've submitted an application for citizenship by grant. Citizenship by grant is only possible if the person intends to continue living in NZ, while claiming citizenship by descent is available for people living anywhere.

Comment: @GregHewgill That's not very important but I am even more confused than before. Your answer to user102008 led me to believe that your daughter was already a citizen by descent but that she was only admitted as a permanent resident because she wasn't documented.

Comment: @Relaxed: I'm not sure exactly where the confusion lies, but feel free to email me and I'll be happy to clarify.

Answer (score 9):

It varies according to country.  And if the country does not have a rule, there is a United Nations directive that kicks in to prevent the baby from being stateless.  In the United Kingdom, your question is **explicitly addressed** in the [British Nationality Act 1981](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1981/61).

> For the purposes of this Act a person born outside the United Kingdom aboard a ship or aircraft—
>
> - (a) shall be deemed to have been born in the United Kingdom if—
>
>   - (i) at the time of the birth his father or mother was a British citizen; or
>   - (ii) he would, but for this subsection, have been born stateless,
>
>   and (in either case) at the time of the birth the ship or aircraft was registered in the United Kingdom or was an unregistered ship or aircraft of the government of the United Kingdom; but
> - (b) subject to paragraph (a), is to be regarded as born outside the United Kingdom, whoever was the owner of the ship or aircraft at that time, and irrespective of whether or where it was then registered.

Basically, the baby has a claim to British citizenship if either parent is British *OR* the baby would be left stateless.

The question of whether the child's claim is **British Otherwise Than By Descent** or **British By Descent**.  The citizenship class of  **British Otherwise Than By Descent** is the preferred class (i.e., Native Brit), but the laws governing this aspect are profoundly complex.  If a person is British By Descent, they cannot pass their citizenship to their children unless the child is born physically on this island (or NI).  https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/262401/chapter20.pdf

For completeness' sake: if a baby is born inside the UK (or on a British aircraft that lands in the UK) and neither parent is British, the baby gets their citizenship from one of the parents.  The baby's visa status is called **tolerated**.  **Tolerated** status holds until the baby leaves the UK, and then they must have a proper visa before returning.  If the baby remains in the UK for 10 years without leaving, they acquire British Citizenship via the British Nationality Act 1981,

Comment: great reference

Comment: Oh, yeah.  Birth _at sea_ between countries was probably common, and I'd suspect most countries have laws from that time which would still apply to airlines.  In that case, most countries _would_ have laws for this.

Comment: @MooingDuck most countries with a coast and harbor at least.

Comment: Most countries, including the largest and most populous ones, do have a coast:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landlocked_country#mediaviewer/File:Landlocked_nations.svg

Answer (score 1):

In Canada they automatically become a Canadian Citizen :(

It's named jus soli (Latin), or right of soil, as opposed to jus sanguinis, or right of blood. The citizenship policy is unique, among developed nations, to Canada and (at one point, not sure if it still is) the USA.

It was put in place in the 1947 Citizenship Act when people would come and would leave behind their countries of origin. Our government has been fighting to change the laws for a few years after a 'scam' came to light in 2011, in which Chinese women where coached to avoid detection of their pregnancy at the border, lie low until they gave birth to an automatically Canadian child. Then they can take advantage of Canada’s health care and education, and when the child turns 18 he sponsors the parents to migrate to Canada.

Comment: [*Jus soli*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jus_soli) is not unique to Canada; it is widespread among the countries of the Americas including the USA (the [14th amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourteenth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution)), and a handful of other countries around the world. The "scam" to which you refer is often called [birth tourism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birth_tourism).

Comment: This answer seems more related to the linked question about nationality.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on things you can claim the citizenship of the airline, as there is some law (was told during my training but now long since forgotten) that until you exit the aircraft, you are under the protectorate of the country of the plane's registration. E.g., if the plane was USA registered, and you are born midair between Oz and NZ, then you are under the protection of the USA. Never thought to ask which citizenship though. But the same happens on a boat at sea.

Comment: The problem with that statement is not all countries allow for citizenship by birth on soil.